# ploting replicates in ggplot problems with annotation per facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr

I have a large dataframe.
Here is fake data of a similar structure;

```
dat = data.frame(id=seq(1:12),variable=rep(c("p1","p2","p3"),times=2),value=c(runif(6),runif(6)+1),locus=c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6)),replicate=rep(c(1,2),6), TimesLocus=rep(2,times=12))
```

I would like to plot the correlation between replicate 1, and replicate 2.

I have achieved this using.

```
Corr<-cor(dat[dat$replicate==1,]$value,dat[dat$replicate==2,]$value)
ggplot(dat,aes(x=dat[dat$replicate==1,]$value,y=dat[dat$replicate==2,]$value))+
  geom_point()+xlab("replicate1")+ylab("replicate2")+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")  + 
  annotate("text", x = 0.9*max(dat[dat$replicate==1,]$value),
       y = 0.9*max(dat[dat$replicate==2,]$value),
       label = paste("r^2=",round(Corr,digits=2),sep=" "),color="blue")
```

However, now  I want to see if the correlations are different PER VARIABLE.

I can do this using.

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x=dat[dat$replicate==1,]$value,y=dat[dat$replicate==2,]$value))+
 geom_point()+xlab("replicate1")+ylab("replicate2")+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")  + facet_wrap(~variable)
```

If I want to have the correlation per variable I know that I should make a separate dataframe, but I am having problems with this.

```
r_df <- ddply(dat, .(variable), summarise, 
          rsq=round(summary(lm(dat[dat$replicate==2,]$value~
                                    dat[dat$replicate==1,]$value))$r.squared, 2))
```

It gives the same r2ed for each variable.

What am I doing wrong?  Can I do this without reshaping my data again?

Okay, I am now trying to use info from @shadow, and have the following.

```
 r_df_val <- ddply(df_mlt_loc_Dup, .(variable), summarise, rsq=round(summary(lm(value[replicate==2]~value[replicate==1]))$r.squared, 2))
```

Some how the calculation isn't correct.  All of the rsq are 0.06 or something, when they should be near 0.8, you can see the correlation in the plot below.  Is it somehow re-ordering the dataframe upon subsetting by variable?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your `ddply` call, you used `dat` again. That refers to the original data. You should instead directly use `value` and `replicate`. Then they are interpreted correctly.

```
r_df <- ddply(dat, .(variable), summarise, 
              rsq = round(summary(lm(value[replicate==2]~value[replicate==1]))$r.squared, 2))
```

This does not work for the data you provided, because the datasets are too small. But for your original data it should work. Also here's a larger dataset (essentially the data you provided with some additional rows). For this data it should work as desired.

```
dat = data.frame(id=seq(1:24),variable=rep(c("p1","p2","p3"),times=4),value=c(runif(12),runif(12)+1),locus=c(rep("A",12),rep("B",12)),replicate=rep(c(1,2),12), TimesLocus=rep(2,times=24))
```

Comment: thanks, I used your correct syntax, but somehow the calculations are incorrect, see plots above, thanks